# Invalid syntaxt sum(list) >= 2

Tags: python, rasa

I get an invalid syntax error at:

```
if sum(severe_symptoms_list) >= 2
```

I have set the values for the severe and moderate symptoms slots to True and False depending on what answer was given by the user to a YES/NO question. What have i done wrong ?

```
class ActionHowManySymptoms(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_how_many_symptoms"

    def run (self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

        severe_symptom1 = tracker.get_slot('severe_symptom_one')
        severe_symptom2 = tracker.get_slot('severe_symptom_two')
        severe_symptom3 = tracker.get_slot('severe_symptom_three')
        severe_symptom4 = tracker.get_slot('severe_symptom_four')

        moderate_symptom1 = tracker.get_slot('moderate_symptom_one')
        moderate_symptom2 = tracker.get_slot('moderate_symptom_two')
        moderate_symptom3 = tracker.get_slot('moderate_symptom_three')
        moderate_symptom4 = tracker.get_slot('moderate_symptom_four')

        severe_symptoms_list = [severe_symptom1, severe_symptom2, severe_symptom3, severe_symptom4]
        moderate_symptoms_list = [moderate_symptom1, moderate_symptom2, moderate_symptom3, moderate_symptom4]

        True = 1

        if sum(severe_symptoms_list) >= 2
            dispatcher.utter_response(response="utter_some_severe_symptoms", tracker)
        elif sum(severe_symptoms_list) == 1
            dispatcher.utter_response(response="utter_one_severe_symptoms", tracker)
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_response(response="utter_no_severe_symptoms", tracker)         

        if sum(moderate_symptoms_list) >= 2
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_some_moderate_symptoms")
        elif sum(moderate_symptoms_list) == 1
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_one_moderate_symptoms")
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_no_moderate_symptoms")         

        return[]
```

Comment: you don't have colons after the conditionals

Comment: thank you, im new to pythong and completely missed it, i feel dumb for such a simple error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to code in a more decent presentable manner. It will help you in the long run

```
if (sum(severe_symptoms_list) >= 2):
```

Comment: what do you mean by "decent" and "presentable"

Comment: It is always recommended to code using the standard fashion. I meant this as "decent" and "presentable". This is because if you switch into another language, you wouldnt have to change much of your style. Also, sometimes you might have to visit the code you had written ages back and when you do, you have to understand what you have done. This is why it will help you in the long run